# How do i show the selected value in a multiple ui-bootstrap dropdown menu?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a ng-repeat that generates two dropdown menus with different values in them, now i what to show the selected value for each of the menus.

It will work fine to send `filter.name` to `setFilter` function and bind span with `ng-bind="some $scope.variable"` **if** there is only one menu **but not** with multiple.

```
<span class="dropdown" ng-repeat="filterGroup in filterGroups">
      <a href class="dropdown-toggle" >
        {{filterGroup.groupName}} <span>this is where i what to show the selected value</span> <span class="caret"></span>&nbsp;
      </a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li ng-repeat="filter in filterGroup.filters">
            <a dropdown-toggle ng-click="setFilter(filter.name);"> {{filter.name}} </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
</span>`
```

here is a plunker : [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/84aM9sDsiOLFzITCZz4V?p=preview)

**Is there a fancy way to do this?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with one solution to my problem (not sure if it is the best)

First i put the id of my `filterGroup` to the `<span>`

Then i pass name and id to `setFilter()`

And my `setFilter` function i added `$("#"+id).text(data);`

**Html**

```
<span class="dropdown" ng-repeat="filterGroup in filterGroups">
  <a href class="dropdown-toggle" >
    {{filterGroup.groupName}} <span id="{{filterGroup.id}}"></span>  <span class="caret"></span>
 </a>
   <ul class="dropdown-menu">
     <li ng-repeat="filter in filterGroup.filters">
        <a dropdown-toggle ng-click="setFilter(filter.name, filterGroup.id);"> {{filter.name}} </a>
     </li>
  </ul>
</span>
```

**Javascript**

```
$scope.setFilter = function(data, id){
   $("#"+id).text(data);
};
```

Here is a working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/84aM9sDsiOLFzITCZz4V?p=preview)

**If anyone has a better solution to this please let my know**

hi ho! cherry-0